# How to Prevent "False" Input Binding Updates (Angular 2+)?

Tags: angular, angular-components, two-way-binding

Let's say I have two components. A `ParentComponent` and a `ChildComponent`. The `ParentComponent` has a `age` property and two-way bindings with the `ChildComponent`.

### ParentComponent

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"

@Component({
    selector: "app-parent",
    template: "<app-child [(age)]="age"></app-child>"
})
export class ParentComponent {
    age = 25
}
```

### ChildComponent

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core"

@Component({
    selector: "app-child",
    template: "<p>{{ age }}</p>"
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input()
    age = 0

    @Output()
    ageChange = new EventEmitter()

}
```

Whenever the value of `age` changes in the `ParentComponent`, Angular propagates the change to the `ChildComponent`. And when `ChildComponent` emits the `ageChange` event, the changes are synced back to the `ParentComponent`. When the latter happens, the `ParentComponent` detects that its property has changed and propagates the changes to the child. But the child already has the new value!

This seems inefficient. Is there a way to prevent this "false" update? Am I missing something or is this how Angular works?

Comment: You could take a look at `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, to prevent unnecessary change detection.

Comment: @cyr-x As I understand, `OnPush` only propagates the changes (and calls the lifecycle hooks on the child) when the reference of a binding changes. When the child emits a new value, wouldn't the reference change?

Comment: For your particular case, no because your data is a native type, therefore the value itself represents the reference. If it where an object, it depends how you created that object. But overall it doesn't matter, because with `onPush` angular would run the change-detection for the child, everytime an output or an input changes, which doesn't really impact the performance (you won't notice it).